# Disable remote PC showing logon screen when connected using Microsoft Remote Desktop iPhone app?

Tags: windows-8.1, remote-desktop, iphone

I have a desktop PC running Windows 8.1 which I can successfully connect to from my iPhone using the Microsoft Remote Desktop app. The problem is that, **when connected, the PC shows the logon screen**, and if I try logging on directly on the PC my iPhone is disconnected.
I think this is known as 'curtain mode' in Google's similar Chrome Remote Desktop app.
**The same session is shown on both, but not at the same time** if that makes sense - e.g. I can open stuff on my iPhone, disconnect and logon directly on the PC and see the stuff I just opened. But I want to be able to **view the computer on both the monitor and the iPhone** as the PC is in my room and I want to be able to watch TV programmes, etc. without having to get up to change volume, etc.
In the past I've used TeamViewer which has been fine but I already have the Microsoft RD app on my phone and I'm trying to avoid unnecessarily installing more apps.

**Is it possible to do this using Microsoft's RDP or will I have to use a third-party app such as TeamViewer or VNC?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 3rd Party app - RDP is behaving as intended; only one user can be logged to any given session, logging from any other location will, as you discovered, terminate any other session.